# Ion Error when loading https url

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-ion, ion-koush

I am using Koushik Dutta's [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) networking library for Android.

I want to make a connection to instagram’s api through this address: https://instagram.com/api/
But when trying via ion, it works with some ISPs and doesn’t work with some others and throws an exception.
It seems that it’s because of the address starting with https, because it works fine with http .
 I’d appreciate your help
Thanks for your guides in advance

Log :

```
03-02 12:46:51.042: E/instagram_log(3770): (30241 ms) https://instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/: Connection error
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  null
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$2.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:247)
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:708)
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:725)
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:626)
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:41)
03-02 12:46:51.045: E/instagram_log(3770):  at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:568)
03-02 12:46:51.155: W/System.err(3770):     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
03-02 12:46:51.156: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$2.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:247)
03-02 12:46:51.172: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:708)
03-02 12:46:51.172: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:725)
03-02 12:46:51.172: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:626)
03-02 12:46:51.172: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:41)
03-02 12:46:51.172: W/System.err(3770):     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:568)
```

Comment: Same error. Any solution ?